# Delegate an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model A that has many of another model B, which has_many of a third model C, and want to delegate A from B to C. For example:

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pets
end

class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :house
  has_many :toys
  delegate :house, to: :toys
end

class Toy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pet
end
```

`> toy.house`

As it stands, I have to use `toy.pet.house`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
class Toy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pet 
  delegate :house, to: :pet 
end
```

And remove

```
delegate :house, to: :toys
```

from `Pet`.

There are at least two problems with:

```
class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :house
  has_many :toys
  delegate :house, to: :toys
end
```

First, an instance of `Toy` doesn't respond to `house`, so you can't `delegate :house, to: :toys`. Second, even if an instance of `Toy` *did* respond to `house`, you wouldn't be able to call that instance method on a collection, which is what `toys` is. So, that's busted all over the place.

`Pet`, however, *does* respond to `house`. And, `Toy belongs_to :pet`. So, you do `Toy delegate :house, to: :pet`. And Bob's your uncle!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:through` option on your ActiveRecord associations to accomplish what you want. Configure your models as follows:

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pets
  has_many :toys, through: :pets
end

class Pet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :house
  has_many :toys
end

class Toy < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :pet
  has_one :house, through: :pet
end
```

Here is a link to the official guide for the [:through option](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) on has_many and has_one associations.